# Best Approach to fetch and update the data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have few questions regarding fetching and updating the data.
For example if i receive number of posts, and I use component level state to handle that.
There are two approaches I use, First one is to call the api inside `componentDidMount` and update the state accordingly

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
  // get data handles all the state changes etc etc 
 }
```

But with this approach, if i have multiple api's and state changes, It causes the component to be messy.
To solve that thing, What i tried was to use HOC for data fetching.

For example

```
const AppWithFetch = withFetching('www.getsomething.com/posts')(MyComponent);
```

here my hoc receives a url and accordingly gives the data as props.
The hoc gives these variables as prop to my component 
--data (initially null)
--isLoading(initially true)
--error(initially false)
and inside my component, Then i don't need componentDidMount and other logic, I just need some conditional rendering by checking, `this.props.isLoading`.
This seems perfect. But then I have another issue which i can't resolve efficiently. Let's say I fetch the data, and now inside my component I make an action or something which causes the data to change, I can't change the data as it is received as a prop. 
In other words I want to separate my view and api logic(including fetching and updating).
I would love some good suggestions.
Thanks

my fetching hoc for now,

```
 const withFetching = (url) => (Component) =>
    class WithFetching extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                data: null,
                isLoading: false,
                error: {
                    error: false,
                    message: null
                },
            };
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({ isLoading: true });
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
            try {
                const { data } = await axios({
                    method: 'get', //you can set what request you want to be
                    url: `${SERVER_URL}${url}`,
                    headers: {
                        'x-auth-Token': token
                    }
                });
                if (validateData(data)) {
                    if (data.status == 'OK') {
                        return this.setState({
                            data: data.data, isLoading: false
                        });
                    }
                    this.setState({
                        error: {
                            error: true,
                            message: data.message
                        },
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                } else {
                    this.error({
                        error: {
                            error: true,
                            message: errorResponse.message
                        },
                        isLoading: false

                    });
                }
            } catch (e) {
                this.error({
                    error: errorResponse.message, isLoading: false
                });
            }
        }

        render() {
            return <Component {...this.props} {...this.state} />;
        }
    };
export default withFetching;
```

Comment: Why don't use Redux or any state container like this ?

Comment: I don't want to use redux for this. There are some screens which just need some data and update it. For my usecase that would be overkill. I can give some overview, Get list of friends(i can use redux), go to that friend(have to track selected friend), then go to his comments etc etc. I don't think that would be good enough approach to use everything via redux even if we don't need./ When we are deeply nested, it becomes very complicated and overkill to use redux for those situations.